# How to reference confidential data in reference list

Tags: citations

I'm writing my BA thesis in computer science at a larger company and need to reference a confidential statistics report that has been made available to me in my reference list.

So my question is, how does one normally cite a confidential source? I assume you would somehow include the contact details of someone at the company with access to the material?

I'm using the Vancouver reference style by the way. Cheers!

Edit: I should clarify that the confidential "report" that was made available to me really isn't a report, but rather just raw data. It doesn't have an author or even a title, only site visitor statistics, thereby my confusion on how to reference it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before you do *anything* with the confidential data, you should have cleared its use with the company in question. Giving away the data in any form without their express permission could get you into a lot of trouble.

That said, if the report containing the data is a internal company technical report, it should be cited as such in a bibliography. This provides enough information for a person to track it down, although you may want to state that it is not available to the general public.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. How would the actual reference list element look though, could you give me an example?

Comment: In journals I would submit to, it would probably be something like: "Author. Technical Report No. XX-YYYY. City: Company, Year." Don't know the Vancouver style, so you'd have to adapt it to that format.

Comment: It doesn't really have a report number or even an author, it's just raw data, see my edit. I apologise for not being clear from the beginning. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, now it becomes the dreaded "Personal Communication." You cite the sender, and the date of the communication. Obviously, someone might ask for this, in which case you will need to redact the data, but show that the correspondence took place. (Unless you can't even do that—in which case that data probably shouldn't be in the thesis in the first place!)

Comment: Thanks, this is a great help. The work I'm doing is in web optimisation and about finding ways to optimise the company's web site. The data was given me in a personal meeting and was a csv file detailing site statistics, which  I use to decide in which browsers to test the optimisations. I'm not allowed to directly quote the data in the thesis, but instead make statemenets like "IE9, Firefox and Chrome are the three most common browsers used to access the site and therefore the ones that will be tested". So what information do I give in the references, the person in question's name and email?

Comment: Normally, it's just the name of the individual and the date of the communication. But that depends on the bibliography style.

Answer (score 2):

It may be best to just cite the source as if it were any other reference, then include in your acknowledgements and/or a footnote more details on how you acquired the data and who to contact if it is indeed available to others.

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers to this.

Once, as a researcher, I had the pleasure to use some unpublished data in my forecast. (My paper was about the forecast method itself.) I wrote something along `42. John Doe. In private communication. 1899`, also citing a report that was partially based on the same data. John Doe was the person, who gave me the data. (Thanks, "John"!)

On the other hand, as a supervisor to some BSc-theses that are written at commercial companies, the students are conflicted with internal data all the time. It is hard to cite internal data, esp. in a public thesis. The current way of doing it is to perform an "expert interview". You **talk** with some higher-ups at the company, they provide you both with data and with interpretations of the data.

Then you put the final interview in the appendix of the thesis, it is the primary information source, to which you can refer in other parts of your thesis.